# React native maps : How to add a point with attributes and marker to the map via user interface

Tags: android, react-native, google-maps-markers, react-native-maps, json-server

Hi I hope you are doing well, so I am trying to make a form in which a user can enter some parameters (name of the point and its range (number)) but I don't know how I can get its position (lon, lat) when the user clicks it on the map with a marker. What I have now is a simple map view in the App.js in which I import a basic form component with two text fields and an "Add" button and I want to get these in my json server and for the position as well (but automaticly when the user clicks on the map and a marker should be showing once he clicks), any idea how I can implement this please ? And very thank you in advance friends.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm not really answering your question with my answer, but I've been trying to implement a navigation app before and found it very restricting to work with simple map views.

Instead, I would recommend you try [Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/), it has most things already built-in and offers a nice smooth interface.

I don't know how extensive your work with the user's location is, but I think if it's more than a minimal selection of coordinates, Mapbox is worth a try.

I hope this answer was helpful even though I did not answer your question.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for your reply friend, you suggest using mapbox for implementing the add point form right ? If so, I checked this but I really don't get how it will work with the google maps I am using and I've never used it before so I can't get how it will add the new point.. Can you give me more details please ?

Comment: @kyara my suggestion was that you use Mapbox instead of Google Maps as it is way more user friendly in my experience. They have a great [documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/) and [tutorials](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/?product=Maps+SDK+for+Android) on all sorts of features with [this one](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/marker-symbol-layer/) regarding your problem.